# R problem: Look up date values from vector in another dataframe with rainfall, add total rainfall from certain dates into a total

Tags: r, sum, lookup

I have a vector filled with dates.

Dates <- c(14/10/1997, 20/10/1997, 30/10/1997, ect., ect.)

I have a dataframe with dates, and rainfall on each date.

| Date | Rainfall |
| --- | --- |
| 10/10/1997 | 10 |
| 11/10/1997 | 0.2 |
| 12/10/1997 | 0 |
| 13/10/1997 | 1 |
| 14/10/1997 | 1 |

For each date in the vector:

I have to look up the same date in the dataframe, then add up the rainfall for the vector date, and 4 days prior to the date in the vector.

Eg. for vector date 14/10/1997, I would add up: 1 + 1 +0 +0.2 + 10 = 12.2

Then I need to add this to a data frame like:

| Date | 5 day Rainfall |
| --- | --- |
| 14/10/1997 | 12.2 |

Anyone have ideas on how to code this? I am new to R and not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Change dates in the vector and dataframe to Date class. Assuming the dataframe is called `df` you can create a sequence of `Dates` and `Dates - 4`, find the dates in relevant range in `df` and `sum` their  `Rainfall` value.

```
Dates <- c("14/10/1997", "20/10/1997", "30/10/1997")
Dates <- as.Date(Dates, '%d/%m/%Y')
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%d/%m/%Y')

result <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) data.frame(Date = x, 
              five_day_rain = sum(df$Rainfall[df$Date %in% x:y], na.rm = TRUE)), 
              Dates, Dates - 4))
result
```